# Why do I see "Blank" or "0" value at the begging of Stacked Column Chart in Power BI Desktop

Tags: sql-server, powerbi, dax

For some reason stacked column chart displays "Blank" value even though data behind doesn't have any Blank or '0'.

[image]

And my `X-axis` doesnt have `"Type"` where I can choose between `continuous` or `categorical`:

[image]

In a data behind I have 12 months, no blank or 0 :
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `(Blank)` value can occur even though your underlying data set has no blank values. It is because when you have established relationship between tables, and there are other visuals or filters on the same report page, leading to a joining or filter which results in blank values.

It can be hard to pinpoint sometimes, so the easiest thing you can do is to filter it in the `Visual level filters` as follows:

[image: filter]

As for the X-axis `continuous` or `categorical` type setting, it is only available when the data type is [numerics or date/time](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-service-tutorial-customize-x-axis-and-y-axis-properties/). The `MonthShort` column you're using is just text to Power BI and it has no idea in what way it should be continuously linked. You need to use the `MonthNumber` or a date column if you want to achieve so.

[image: continuous]

Comment: That's really good to know. Thank you very much again for your help. Mostly I'm using SSRS 2012, now trying to implement Power BI in my organization. Do you think its gonna worth it?
Thanks

Comment: @Oleg Glad to help! To me SSRS is reporting tool for creating paginated, operational reports, while Power BI is dashboard tool for data exploration and analysis. They serve different purposes and it's definitely worth trying as Power BI is much easier to use and cheap (or free).